# Adding dynamic values to MongoDB embedded collections

Tags: mongodb, express, mongoose

I am developing an expressJS application. I have a user schema with embedded collections. I was wondering if there are any techniques that I can use inorder to post embedded collections dynamically. For instance :

Below I have "a" embedded collection with 2 values x and y. Is it possible to post values dynamically instead of having x and y what if I wanna post x---xn ?

```
var user = mongoose.Schema(
{
_id: {type: String, required:true},
name : String,
a: {
x: {sensor_id: String, sname: String, time:String, value: Number },
y: {sensor_id1: String, sname1: String, time1:String, value1: Number }
},
a1 : {
x: {sensor_id2: String, sname2: String, time2:String, value2: Number},
y: {sensor_id3: String, sname3: String, time3:String, value3: Number }
}});
```

While I want to post values I do like this :

```
var user = new User();
user.a.x.sensor_id = req.body.sensor_id;
user.a.y.sname = req.body.sname;
```

I was wondering if there are some techniques so I can post any number of values to the embedded collection "a"?

Comment: I have some edits. Please let me know if you have any questions ?

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried this ?

```
var user = mongoose.Schema(
{
 _id: {type: String, required:true},
 name : String,
 a:[ {
      x: {sensor_id: String, sname: String, time:String, value: Number },
      y: {sensor_id1: String, sname1: String, time1:String, value1: Number }
  }]
});
```

Then After..

```
var user = new User();
user.a = [{x:sensor_id},{y:req.body.sensor_id},{x:sensor_id2},{y:req.body.sensor_id2}];
```